# Laravel - unable to establish connection between two tables in database

Tags: php, laravel

so I'm try to "connect" two tables using `belongsTo` and `hasMany` but it doesn't seem to be working... I'll link my code down below, if there is anything else you might need to fully understand the problem, please feel free to ask!

**pages.notification**

```
<section class="all-notifications">
            @each('partials.notification', $sent_notifications, 'notification')
            @each('partials.notification', $received_notifications, 'notification')
        </section>
```

**partials.notification**

```
<div class="singular-notification">
    <div class="notification-title">
        <a href="/event/{{ $notification->event->id }}">
            {{ $notification->event->name }}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE event (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   owner_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   description TEXT NOT NULL,
   tag TEXT,
   start_datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL CHECK (start_datetime >= now()),
   end_datetime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL CHECK (end_datetime > start_datetime),
   price FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0,
   max_capacity INT DEFAULT NULL,
   attendee_counter INT DEFAULT 0 CHECK (attendee_counter <= max_capacity AND attendee_counter >= 0),
   location TEXT NOT NULL,
   image TEXT NOT NULL,
   is_private BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
   is_full BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
);

CREATE TABLE notification (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   event_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES event(id),
   sent_users_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) CHECK (sent_users_id != receiver_users_id),
   receiver_users_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
   status notification_status NOT NULL
);
```

**NotificationController.php**

```
public function list($id)
{
  if (!Auth::check()) return redirect('/login');

  $sent_notifications = DB::table('notification')->where('sent_users_id', $id)->orderBy('id')->get();
  $received_notifications = DB::table('notification')->where('receiver_users_id', $id)->orderBy('id')->get();
  return view('pages.notifications', ['sent_notifications' => $sent_notifications, 'received_notifications' => $received_notifications]);
}
```

**Event.php**

```
public function notifications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Notification');
}

public function notification() {
    return $this->hasMany(Notification::class);
}
```

**Notification.php**

```
public function event() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Event');
}

public function events() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
```

The error I'm getting is `Undefined property: stdClass::$event` and I can't seem to get around it... please let me know if there's an easy fix.

Thanks alot for your time

Comment: the error is related to how you are setting `$notification`. can you add the related code to that ?

Comment: The event and notification relationships should be other way around: i.e: 
```public function notification() {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
    }``` and vice versa

Comment: @N69S done! is that it?

Comment: @AliRaza didn't work...

Comment: @GuilhermeMoreira not the relation definition. How are you getting the variable `$notification` that you are using in your view ?

Comment: @N69S it's in the first html code, `@each('partials.notification', $sent_notifications, 'notification')`

Comment: and how are you getting the variable `$sent_notifications` ? put all relevant code in your question directly.

Comment: its in **NotificationController.php**, function called `list`

Comment: Your issue can be fixed using the Model class instead of DB class directly. answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `DB::table()` you get instances of StdClass as results (or array of StdClass) so you cant use methods declared in your model Notification class.

You need to query starting from the model

```
$sent_notifications = Notification::where('sent_users_id', $id)->orderBy('id')->get();
$received_notifications = Notification::where('receiver_users_id', $id)->orderBy('id')->get();
```

This will get you a collection of Notification::class instances and you can use declared relations as well as any method declared in your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Always use best code practices and always use code that helps you, not code that is an obstacle.

If you have relationship there 1:n like `$event` has many `$notifications`, use those singulars and plurals in names

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Notification::class);
    }
}

class Notification extends Model
{
    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }
}
```

Remove those duplicated methods. What I wrote here is what is considered for good practice. More good advices you can also find [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices).

Comment: is there any differente between using `belongsTo(Event::class);` and `belongsTo('App\Models\Event');` ?

Comment: No difference. Actually, `Event::class` is evaluated to fully namespaced class name (you can test it with `dd(Event::class);`). Personally, I use `Event::class` way, but most important is to be consistent and use it same way everywhere in project.

Comment: ohh I see, so in terms of functionalities they are the same

Comment: @GuilhermeMoreira Correct. [Example no. 2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).